# I try to have entries by searching for a boolean with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Good evening!

I am trying to get with yq the entries looking for a boelan value inside a yml.

e.g:

```
 yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] | select( .persistence == "true")' manifest.yml
```

But this does not return anything... this would be the yml where I look for:

```
applications:
  a:
    enabled: true
    project: ../../../aproj
    version: v1.0.1
    persistence: true
  b:
    enabled: false
    project: ../../bproj
    version: v1.0.1
  c:
    enabled: true
    project: ../../../cproj
    version: v1.0.1
    persistence: true
```

the output should be the following entries: a,c

Comment: In order for us to provide actual answers with concrete solutions, please provide in your question [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using ([mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) or [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)), and what "the output should be the following entries: a,c" actually means (is it just the field names `a` and `c`, is it the objects contained in `.applications.a` and `.applications.c`, or is it the whole input object with the fields in `.applications` reduced to `.a` and `.c`?).

Comment: I think I am using mikefarah/yq I have been able to get it out as follows:

`yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.persistence == true) .key' manifest.yml | xargs echo |  sed 's/ /, /g'`

and this is the output:

`a, c`

thanks 

@pmf

Comment: You don't need `xargs` and `sed`. Try `yq '.applications | to_entries | map(select(.value.persistence).key) | join(", ")' manifest.yml`.

Comment: I need the result to be inside square brackets and double commas like this:

`["a", "c"]`

and this is the way I have achieved it:

`yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.persistence == true) .key' manifest.yml | xargs echo | sed 's/ /\",\"/g' | sed  's/^/[\"/' | sed s/$/\"]/`

Comment: That's why I was asking you to clarify the exact shape of your desired output. You still don't need `xargs` and `sed`. Stay in `yq` and use the `@json` builtin: `yq '.applications | to_entries | map(select(.value.persistence).key) | @json' manifest.yaml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of another question - but for completion:

```bash
yq '.applications[] | select(.persistence == true) | key' file.yaml
```

Explanation:

- `.applications[]` Expand all the map values in applications
- `select(.persistence == true)` select the ones with persistence = true
- `key` get their key

Disclaimer: I wrote yq